# Create a List From Input Separated by Commas And Find the Sum of the List with For/While Loops

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to Python and am currently working on the following problem. It seems simple but I keep getting lost in value errors.

Here's the requirements:

Write a program that allows the user to input as many integers as they would like, separated by commas and then add these integers together using both a while loop and a for loop. You will need to perform the following steps:

- Ask the user to enter integers separated by commas.
- Convert the input to a list of integers.
- Calculate the sum of the integers in the list in two ways:
- First, use a while loop to calculate the sum and then display the sum.
- Then, use a for loop to calculate the sum and display the sum.

My code so far:

```
# First thing I do is enter an input
input_string = input(('Enter elements of a list separated by commas: '))
# Followed by splitting the string into a list:
user_list = (input_string.split())
```

After this I'm supposed to do some calculations on `user_list` with a `for`/`while` loop, but I can't because it's a `string` and every time I try to convert it into an integer I get some sort of error. If anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `sum(int(n) for n in input('numbers').split(','))` - you need to split on the comma right now you are just doing `.split()` or just use map `sum(map(int, input('numbers').split(',')))`

Comment: Don't get us to do your homework for you. Show what you tried, and ask a question about the problems you encountered. Provide a [mre] that reproduces your problem, and the full traceback of any errors. See [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the forced use of `while` loop is kind not really necessary when a `for` loop is more appropriate.  so in this example we use the `while` loop to convert our list of `str` to `int` as we total it up.  the we use the list we modified in the `for` loop.

```py
input_string = input('Enter elements of a list separated by commas: ')

user_list = input_string.split(',')
user_list_len = len(user_list)
count = 0
total = 0

while count < user_list_len:
    user_list[count] = int(user_list[count].strip())
    total += user_list[count]
    count += 1
print(total)

total = 0
for item in user_list:
    total += item
print(total)
```